# Copying Facebook Profile Picture Creates a 0kb Image File

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fopen

This used to work and now it doesn't on my server. This is kind of a last ditch effort to try to figure out what is going wrong here. I'm simply trying to copy a profile image from Facebook to a folder on my server. Here's the only code I'm using:

```
file_put_contents("..//images/artist_pictures/artist_216.jpg", file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/553451657/picture?type=large"));
```

After that runs I get a 0kb image file called artist_216.jpg. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too good with PHP, but I know that the picture URL you're using is a redirect to another file on Facebook's CDN. I'm guessing you need to somehow resolve the actual location and pull the contents of the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust your `php.ini` file.

Change `allow_url_fopen = Off` to `allow_url_fopen = on`.